# Firefox How to monitor tab memory usage without using about: memory?

Tags: html, firefox, user-interface, firebug, frontend

How to monitor tab memory usage without using about: memory in Firefox? It looks like the about:memory result is not very user friendly.

Is there any good tool to use in Firefox like Task Manager in Chrome to monitor tab memory usage?

Update: I just find I can use a plugin in Firefox called Memchaser to monitor memory usage in Firefox  [Memchaser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memchaser/)

Comment: Partially duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216528/how-to-know-each-tab-memory-usage/587822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Firefox`, I've made an addon which displays tab memory usage in the corresponding tab's title.

Provides user with tab related stats and memory usage ..

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-data/

[image: screenshot]

**Features**

- How many tabs are currently open
- How many tabs have been opened during this Firefox session
- How many tabs have been opened since addon installed
- Display tab memory usage in title
- Preference to toggle tab memory usage on/off
- Preference to set interval between memory usage collection

Comment: Hello good sir. Would you by any chance have a plan to upgrade your add-on to be compatible with the latest versions of Firefox ?

Answer (score 8):

Try using `about:performance`. It seems to give real-time data similar to Chrome's Task Manager.

The add-ons don't work in Firefox Quantum, since the add-on framework has been changed now.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer, the other answers now look outdated.

Answer (score 4):

I use Tab Memory instead, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-memory-usage/?src=ss

Tab Data freezes my Firefox